# Is it possible to trigger a popup/dialog through Microsoft Teams Meeting Extension App?

Tags: microsoft-teams, popupwindow, teams-toolkit

I want to get a dialog/popup window up during a teams meeting through my app in a meeting when something is triggered by the meeting organizer. I have found options called "meetingSidePanel", "meetingStage" that can be used in the manifest which allows us to display a screen of the app in meeting side panel and meeting stage but they are not exactly popups and is more like sharing a screen of the app.

Below is a sample provided by microsoft which can be added as side panel in the meeting. Is it possible to generate a popup in the meeting which would be triggered through the meeting extension app? If so, what is the process?
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/meeting-recruitment-app

I want to be able to get a dialog like this up in a teams meeting but it will not necessarily be a poll. I could not find any sample from Microsoft that has implemented something like this. Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: @HashTable-Are you trying the same?
https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-library-js/assets/93527375/33244f7f-00dd-4ea5-b47c-1c8cf6ca8f85
also please refer the below sample-https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/meetings-details-tab/csharp
Just add the context in configurable tab manifest file-  "context": [
        "meetingSidePanel",
        "meetingStage"
      ]

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT Thanks for referring to the dialog sample.  I was looking for something similar but my goal is to get the very same dialog to open for all. For example, let's say if I am the organizer and I open the dialog through my app, I want that dialog to open in the screen of all the meeting attendees . I've implemented the dialog now but I've noticed that when 1 user opens the dialog, it's not visible to the other users. Is there a way to achieve this? I do not expect any input from the attendees. My goal is to just display a message through a popup for a certain time & then close it.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT The basic idea is organizer will trigger the opening of the dialog. After that, a dialog will open in the screen of all the meeting attendees display some message and maybe some links which users should be able to click. The users in the meeting should be able to individually close the dialog that appears on their meeting screen respectively.

Comment: Please have look into this sample-https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/meetings-notification/csharp
Hope it is helpful!!

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT Thanks for the sample. Is it possible to get the dialog to open in the meeting screen(not meeting chat) of all the meeting attendees without the use of a bot once the meeting organizer starts the meeting?
I was previously able to get a dialog up in the meeting screen/stage without the use of a bot using the "meetings-details-tab" app sample that you had previously linked me with but that dialog had opened only in the screen of the trigger-er(organizer). If it is possible to get this working for all attendees, I would be able to stick to this version of code without using bot.

Comment: Could you please check the below related thread-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1345883/how-to-get-dialog-triggered-by-meeting-organizer-t